# Flexible absolute element height

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem with the absolute div height.

Description:

1. `.wrapper` - I want the wrapper to be auto height but limited with max-height. (No scroll for wrapper)
2. `.title` - Just a title
3. `.content` - Here's where problem starts. I want the content div to be scrolled vertically(Y). But if I don't give a height to the wrapper I can't make it scroll. But I don't want the wrapper to be a fixed height.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smz29erj/) of the below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 70%;
  background-color: green;
}
.title {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/mdb5dzxL/3/

Note the height:100% on the html,body

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  max-height:70%;
  background-color: green;
}

.title{
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.content{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position:relative;
}
</style>
```

Edit: I just re-read the question and realised that this doesn't quite answer it.  The original request was to have an "auto" height on the .wrapper, but the height in the above example will always be 70%.  Here's a solution that could work, provided that you are willing to use CSS3 (not supported in IE8 and below):  http://jsfiddle.net/mdb5dzxL/4/

```
<style type="text/css">
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #008000;
    max-height: calc(70% - 50px);
    width: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.title{
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:-50px;
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
}

.content{
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You left the html and body CSS out of your fiddle.

Comment: Hello this is what I looking for. does calc works cross browser?

Comment: @TugsuuGanbat - `calc()` has reasonable support including IE9+ - [Here is a complete list of browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). There are also javascript fallbacks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: green;
}

.title{
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```